# CMD variable substitution for parameters

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

I'm trying to get the CMD equivalent of the following `bash` feature:

```
$ FOO=foo.bar
$ BAR=bar
$ BAZ=baz
$ echo ${FOO/$BAR/$BAZ}
foo.baz
```

Now, CMD has somehwat similar command subsitution when both the pattern and the substitution are 
constant:

```
C:\>set FOO=foo.bar
C:\>set BAR=bar
C:\>set BAZ=baz
C:\>echo %FOO:bar=baz%
foo.baz
```

However, I can't seem to reference variables in there -

```
C:\>echo %FOO:%BAR%=%BAZ%%
%foo:bar=baz%
```

How would I do that? Bonus points for pointing out something that also works inside a `FOR`  loop in a batch file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following (batch file) should work and prints "foo.baz":

```
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set FOO=foo.bar
  set BAR=bar
  set BAZ=baz

  echo !FOO:%BAR%:%BAZ%!
```

(About the FOR-loop thing you mention, you need to give more information on what exactly you mean.)

Comment: Thanks, that works, inside a loop as well (my %BAR% and %BAZ% values are stable over the loop, luckily...).

Answer (score 2):

From command line:
`call echo %FOO:%bar%=%baz%%`

In batch and for loop:

```
@echo off
  set FOO=foo.bar
  set BAR=bar
  set BAZ=baz
for %%N in (baz ban bak) do (
 set BAZ=%%N_AndSomething
 call :expand 
)
goto :eof

:expand
call echo %%FOO:%BAR%=%BAZ%%%
goto :eof
```

You may optimize it by using delayed expansion instead of second call  (calls are expensive), but that was already shown so I left it as an example of syntax. If you do not need to set variable used in substitution inside `for` block you can simplify it further.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the use of CALL to interpolate variables!